# Nested for loop (list comprehension) in python; outer loop not looping

Tags: python, nested, list-comprehension

I am trying to compare data from columns from two different files. I've attempted to use a `for`, and now a `list comprehension`.

The issue is that the outer for loop is not being iterated through, but the inner one is. I've checked individually and iteration is just fine; but once I nest I get this issue. Is there something I missing with this?

```
import csv

newInv  = csv.reader(open("new.csv", "r"))
origInv = csv.reader(open("old.csv", "r"))

print [ oldrow[5] + " " + newrow[3]  for oldrow in origInv for newrow in newInv ]
```

Comment: You should be more specific and accurate in the description of what you are trying to achieve. You are talking about comparaison and I don't see any comparaison in your code. Does it works with the `for` loop ? If not, why trying `list comprehensions` (which is an optimization at your level)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The outer is iterated. However, the inner loop is only executed for the *first* iteration of the outer loop - then the end of newInv has been reached.

Understand that `newInv` is **not a set that you can iterate over multiple times**. It is an iterator that you can use only once. Try this (untested):

```
newInv  = list(csv.reader(open("new.csv", "r")))
origInv = list(csv.reader(open("old.csv", "r")))
```

which will copy the data into memory and allow you to iterate over multiple times.

Answer (score 9):

Note that in your solution the for loops are nested, so that's why one loop seems to iterate while the other one doesn't seem to.

What you need to use to get one element of both iterators at a time is `itertools.izip`:

```
[ oldrow[5] + " " + newrow[3]
for oldrow, newrow in itertools.izip(origInv, newInv)]
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two things going on here.

1) Your list comprehension has two iterations in it. Conceptually, you are asking to re-iterate over `newInv` for every `oldrow`.

2) The reason you don't see every combination of (oldRow, newRow), like you'd expect given the first point, is that a `csv.reader` is a **stream**, and thus can only be iterated over once. Each subsequent "iteration" over `newInv` finds no new items, because they were all "used up" the first time.

To get every combination of (old row, new row), form `list`s from each `csv.reader` first (you can pass them directly to the `list` constructor.

To get one sequence of pair-wise combinations of (old row, new row), `zip` the two `csv.reader`s together.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a simple problem with your brackets.

```
print [[(expression with i and j) for i in foo] for j in bar]
```

Comment: Your list brackets are mismatched. You need another `[`.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs

```
itertools.product(*iterables[, repeat])
Cartesian product of input iterables.
```

Equivalent to nested for-loops in a generator expression. For example, product(A, B) returns the same as ((x,y) for x in A for y in B).

The nested loops cycle like an odometer with the rightmost element advancing on every iteration. This pattern creates a lexicographic ordering so that if the input’s iterables are sorted, the product tuples are emitted in sorted order.

To compute the product of an iterable with itself, specify the number of repetitions with the optional repeat keyword argument. For example, product(A, repeat=4) means the same as product(A, A, A, A).

This function is equivalent to the following code, except that the actual implementation does not build up intermediate results in memory:

```
def product(*args, **kwds):
    # product('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy Dx Dy
    # product(range(2), repeat=3) --> 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111
    pools = map(tuple, args) * kwds.get('repeat', 1)
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)
```

New in version 2.6.